# TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__.apps is undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to make a social media application in React Native with Firebase, but I keep getting this error: *TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__.apps is undefined* the error is coming from the following lines in my App.js file (lines 23-25):

```
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
```

The interesting thing is, the error only appears when I load the app on the local website. If I use an emulator or my Iphone to test the app, there is no error.

Here is my App.js file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { LogBox, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Feather from '@expo/vector-icons/Feather'
import { useFonts, Nunito_400Regular as NunitoRegular, Nunito_700Bold as NunitoBold } from '@expo-google-fonts/nunito';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigator from './src/navigation/index';

import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB1TxcRpLQq0Zqs0f0FvPitIto0tZo_0xM",
  authDomain: "shutter-42e70.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "shutter-42e70",
  storageBucket: "shutter-42e70.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "149059508529",
  appId: "1:149059508529:web:0dbc5bbbb75bf022ef7810"
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

// The theme we'll be using for our navigator
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: '#FAFAFA'
  },
};

// Loads the Feather icons (https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/)
function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default function App() {

  const [assetsReady, setAssetsReady] = useState(false);

  async function _loadFonts() {
    const iconFontAssets = cacheFonts([Feather.font])
    await Promise.all([...iconFontAssets]);
  }

  // Loads the Nunito font (https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/)
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    NunitoRegular, NunitoBold
  });

  // If the fonts or assets are not loaded, we show a default App Loading screen.
  // Otherwise, we return our Photo Sharing App!
  if (!fontsLoaded || !assetsReady) {
    return <AppLoading
              startAsync={_loadFonts}
              onFinish={() => setAssetsReady(true)}
              onError={console.warn}
            />
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
      <Navigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Also here is a link to my github repo in case you want to see my full code: [github repo](https://github.com/bpyle02/Photo-Sharing-App)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the error was in the import of firebase. Where my initial import was

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

I changed it to

```
import firebase as 'firebase/app';
```

This fixed the problem.